# Write Subqueries in Code Igniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

Hello everyone i need a help for writing subqueries on Code Igniter i always fail if i'm using db active record.

Queries that i want to run is

```
select ( alias_a.field_a + alias_b.field_b ) as total_a from
( select sum(field_a) as TOTAL_SUM, status, date from table_a
where status ='ok'
group by year(date)) as alias_a ,

(select sum(field_b) as total_b, status, date from
table_b where
status = 'good' group by year(date)) as alias_b

where year(alias_a.date) = year(alias_b.date)
```

this queries has run on sql editor

i have tried `$this->db->query('my query')` but it has error

any info will helping me so much.
Thanks ! :)

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'gi' (T_STRING)

Thanks sir

Comment: You have syntax error, search for missed braces, semicolon and etc in php code

Comment: Please show the code where you create and use the select statements. Hard to spot the syntax error when we cannot see the syntax used.

Answer (score -1):

Hi please check quotation marks in CI.
could you post the exact code implemented in CI query as is so we could see the problem.

thanks ( =

Comment: really you could just resend your recommendations umitems.